# Android canvas draw path with multiple "drawing tools" and eraser vector (avoid bmps and use transparent bg)

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-drawable

I am working on a program that lets you draw highlights, pen and text comment mark-up. I have a working version where I recycle a bmp 3 times then draw it to the canvas.

The issue is my app has 3 of these views in memory, so that is a lot of bmps being created.

In my current solution, I am trying to avoid bmps. I have extended an ImageView and added the following to the Draw event:

`

```
public override void Draw (Canvas canvas)
{
    base.Draw (canvas);
    HighlightLayer.Draw(canvas, Width, Height);
    PenLayer.Draw(canvas, Width, Height);
    TextLayer.Draw(canvas, Width, Height);
}
```

`

Note that I am using monodroid so it's C# (but nearly the same as Java) and all the "Layer" objects are a subclass of Drawable. Just assume they have draw path commands etc.

Anyway, it sort of works except all the highlights / pen have black boxes around them.

When I draw a line (that's not an eraser), I use PorterDuff.Mode.Src.

I tried to combine the 3 into one bmp instead of recycling it but the issue was that if I had an eraser vector it would erase anything that is already drawn. So an erased pen line would also erase the highlights ...

1. Is it possible to "freeze" a drawing so that as you continue to draw paths on the canvas and change the PorterDuff mode to clear it will not effect anything marked as freeze?
2. I know enough to know that the black box I am seeing around my lines on my Drawables is due to the background bmp not being set. The problem is I want them to be layers on top of the ImageView. If they each retained a background then you could not see the Drawables underneath. How can I use a drawable with the background of the "parent ImageView" and avoid the black background it assumes to be there.

Somehow I need the background of the "parent" ImageView to be applied to the Drawables when it's choosing the transparent fill to avoid the default black.

SOLUTION:

Using the suggestion below I created a LayerDrawable and added Drawables for each mark-up tool. In the Drawable, before drawing the lines I added the following code:

```
public override void Draw (Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.SaveLayer(new RectF(0,0,Bounds.Width(),Bounds.Height()), null, SaveFlags.All);
    canvas.DrawColor(Color.Transparent, PorterDuff.Mode.Clear);
    GraphicsUtil.DrawVector(canvas, Lines, ToolID, Bounds.Width(), Bounds.Height());

}
```

Comment: see Canvas.saveLayer, also you dont need to extend ImageView, just use LayerDrawable with normal ImageView

Comment: Now using a LayerDrawble but I am still seeing black around my lines ...

Comment: so call imageView.setBackgroundColor()

Comment: Right now it's using SetBackgroundDrawable to set to my LayerDrawable, wouldn't that override it? SetBackgroundDrawable(new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { PaperLayer, PageLayer, HighlightLayer, PenLayer, TextLayer }));

Comment: you mean setImageDrawable for showing your LayerDrawable ?

Comment: Yes, I actually just solved this. In my layers that have erasers I do a canvas.SaveLayer followed by canvas.DrawColor(Color.Transparent, PorterDuff.Mode.Clear) before calling the draw vector function.